# Why does math.isclose() fail to detect minor differences between very large values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, precision, equality

`math.isclose()` exists to determine if the difference between two values is within a tolerance.
As far as I understand it, the default values for this tolerance are:

- `rel_tol = 1e-09`
- `abs_tol = 0.0`

If I set both values to `0.0`, then it should be testing if the two values are identical.

This seems to work fine for smaller values:

```
import math

math.isclose(1000, 1000, rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)                       # True
math.isclose(1000, 1001, rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)                       # False
```

But it fails with very large values:

```
import math
import sys

math.isclose(sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize,      rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)    # True
math.isclose(sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize-1,    rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)    # True
math.isclose(sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize-100,  rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)    # True
math.isclose(sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize-1000, rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)    # False
```

It seems that there is still a relative tolerance?

**Why does this behavior occur?**

*The above code was run with Python 3.5.2.*

---

UPDATE 1:

It seems that a similar behavior occurs when using very large float values:

```
import math
import sys

m = sys.float_info.max                                                    # type 'float'

math.isclose(m, m)                                                        # True
math.isclose(m, m-1.0)                                                    # True
math.isclose(m, m-1e100)                                                  # True
math.isclose(m, m-1e300)                                                  # False

math.isclose(m, m,       rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)                        # True
math.isclose(m, m-1.0,   rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)                        # True
math.isclose(m, m-1e100, rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)                        # True
math.isclose(m, m-1e300, rel_tol=0.0, abs_tol=0.0)                        # False
```

On the other hand, the comparison operators do not work here either.

```
import math
import sys

m = sys.float_info.max                                                    # type 'float'

m == m                                                                    # True
m < m                                                                     # False
m > m                                                                     # False

m == m-1.0                                                                # True
m < m-1.0                                                                 # False
m > m-1.0                                                                 # False

m == m-1e100                                                              # True
m < m-1e100                                                               # False
m > m-1e100                                                               # False

m == m-1e300                                                              # False
m > m-1e300                                                               # True
m < m-1e300                                                               # False
```

---

UPDATE 2:

The answer to 'UPDATE 1' was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030217/why-do-comparisions-between-very-large-float-values-fail).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.maxsize` is an integer, but `math.isclose()` works on floating-point values.  On a 64-bit box, `sys.maxsize` has more bits of precision than a float can represent, so `float(sys.maxsize - N) == float(sys.maxsize)` for all sufficiently small postive integer `N`.

```
>>> from sys import maxsize as m
>>> m
9223372036854775807
>>> float(m)
9.223372036854776e+18
>>> float(m - 1)  # identical
9.223372036854776e+18
>>> float(m - 100) # identical 
9.223372036854776e+18
>>> float(m - 1000)  # finally subtracting enough to make a tiny difference
9.223372036854775e+18
```

Short course:  when you want to compare integers for equality, converting to float first simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm confused. `sys.float_info.max` specifies 1.7976931348623157e+308 as the maximum value. How can this be accomplish if it has less range than `sys.maxsize`?

Comment: `sys.float_info.max` is the maximum value a float can have.  There is no inherent limit on the maximum value of a Python integer.  `sys.maxsize` is simply the maximum value a Python integer _used as an index_ can have.  These are three distinct concepts.

Comment: By the way, if you need an introduction to the basics of floating point, just search the web.  For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic   In floating point, there is no particular connection between the number of bits of precision, and the maximum dynamic range (how large the exponent can be).  On your machine, a Python float almost certainly has (exactly) 53 bits of precision, but a dynamic range spanning about 600 (decimal) orders of magnitude (all characteristics of the standard IEEE-754 "double precision" format).

Comment: If I understood it correctly, the above behavior occurs because I use integer values instead of float values. Something similar seems to occur when using very large float values. (I added an example to the question.) I assume that is also because the precision limit gets exceeded. Is there an range where I can operate safely?